# Neo4j - Read Array Property in procedure

Tags: java, arrays, stored-procedures, neo4j

I have one label.It contain one array property name is "LEG_OV_ARR".That is long data type.

**Example:**

> [297, 107, 0, 0, 0, 0] is LEG_OV_ARR array values.

I want to read this array values in my procedure.

My procedure code is :

```
List<String> listArr = (List<String>) node.getProperty("LEG_OV_ARR");
log.info("listArr val "+listArr);
```

I am getting below error:

```
[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.util.List
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

If in this code:

```
Long[] listArr = (Long[]) node.getProperty("LEG_OV_ARR");
log.info("listArr val "+listArr);
```

I am getting below error.

```
[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Long;
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to         
[Ljava.lang.Long
```

How can I fix it.If any possibility please help me...

Comment: You cannot cast a `String` to a `List` or a `Long[]` in Java. What value does `LEG_OV_ARR` contain?

Comment: LEG_OV_ARR  contain [297, 107, 0, 0, 0, 0].

Comment: That value will likely be the String value `"[297, 107, 0, 0, 0, 0]"`. You'll need to parse the String and manually transform it into a `Long[]`.

Comment: But I got empty array if use String[] or Long[]

Comment: Try using something like `node.getProperty("LEG_OV_ARR").substring(1, s.length() - 1).split(", ")` to get a `String[]`. Then you only need to transform the `String[]` into `Long[]`.

Answer (score 1):

The `ClassCastException` tells you exactly the actual [type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#type_signatures) of the object:

```
 Declares a fully qualified type between the L and the semi-colon
 ↓                ↓
[Ljava.lang.String;
↑ ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
| The type, i.e. String
|
An array of the following type
```

Why would you try to cast it to a list of strings then an array of longs anyway, when it tells you it's something ressembling a string? It's actually an array of strings:

```
String[] listArr = (String[]) node.getProperty("LEG_OV_ARR");
log.info("listArr val " + Arrays.toString(listArr));
```

Instead of storing `[297, 107, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, you stored `["297", "107", "0", "0", "0", "0"]`.

Comment: Absolutely right but array contain integers.if use Long[] listArr = (Long[]) node.getProperty("LEG_OV_ARR");
log.info("listArr val "+listArr); its throw [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Long error.

Comment: No it doesn't contain integers, it contains string representations of integers. That's what the runtime exception tells you: you're trying to cast a `String[]` as a `Long[]`, QED the property **is a `String[]`**.

Comment: Ok What is the solution ?

Comment: The solution is in my answer: use a `String[]`... You can then parse numbers from the strings if you need to. Alternatively, change the stored property to a real array of numbers.